# Div element appearing only for seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a table appear when I click on a submit button in a form.
I am using JavaScript for that function.
See code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTable1234() {
        var showtab = document.getElementsByClassName('container12');
        for(var i =0;i !=showtab.length;i++)
            showtab[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code for the button which is calling the above function:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="showTable1234()">Submit</button>
```

This is div element which is to be shown on clicking the submit button:

```
<div class="container12" >
    <h2>Hover Rows</h2>           
    <table class="table table-hover" id = "tab12">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                .....
```

Now as soon as I run the code on the Chrome browser and clicking on submit button, table is visible only but only for mini second or something and the disappears.
It appears again when i click on submit button but again for same amount of time.

I even tried with this code but same result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTable1234() {
        var showtab = document.getElementsByClassName('container12')[0];
        for(var i =0;i !=showtab.length;i++)
            showtab[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

But for this i am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at showTable1234
```

Advance Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53432178/edit) then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: One error is  that you submit the page so you will never see the result - change the button to a button  `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="showTable1234()">Submit</button>` or use AJAX

Comment: The other error is that this is ONE tab `document.getElementsByClassName('container12')[0];` and cannot be looped over. Remove the `[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="showTable1234()">Submit</button>
```

Into this and your issue should be resolved:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="showTable1234()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Already posted this as a comment 15 min before this answer - why bother answering at all?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your submit button is in a form and that it is causing the form to submit. So the JavaScript works, but then the whole page gets refreshed due to the form submit.

To stop the form submit, you can add `onSubmit=“return false”` to the form. You can also stop the submit by returning false from your button’s onClick, or use a button of type `button` rather than `submit`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation

Answer (score -1):

Add a return false at the end of the function and return the returned value of `showTable1234` in the click handler of the button to prevent the default action (which is submitting the form and thus refreshing the page).

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="return showTable1234();">Submit</button>
<script>
function showTable1234() {
   var showtab = document.getElementsByClassName('container12');
   for(var i =0;i !=showtab.length;i++)
   showtab[i].style.display = 'block';
   return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is not recommended to have a submit button and return false. Either preventdefault the form submit or make the submit a button

Comment: @mplungjan Returning false does the same thing as event.preventDefault here. Also, this method is actually quite common.

Comment: It is still not recommended. Use the submit event and return false or preventDefault as you wish

Comment: @mplungjan Why so?

Comment: Always avoid inline event handlers and especially on form elements. Let’s say you have a large firm and one day you add an external validation script using an external file you reuse. Have fun removing all onclicks and onkeyups - or you switch to a framework, in all my code I have separated markup from script, style from content, so I can be sure I am not suddenly submitting twice due to some onclick